# Static Table View Controller with navigation Controller in the flip view controller

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitableview, utility

I want to implement an utility view based iOS app in which i want to implement my app's settings in flipside with the help of static table view enclosed in navigation view controller i have searched the stackoverflow and i got this

[Utility App with Navigation Controller and Table View on FlipSide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546034/utility-app-with-navigation-controller-and-table-view-on-flipside)

but it is not sufficient for me as i am new to iOS

so could somebody teach me how to implement uitableviewcontroller enclosed in uinavigation conrtoller in flipside

Answer (score 0):

have a look at

StaticDataTableViewController 2.0

https://github.com/xelvenone/StaticDataTableViewController

which simplifies working with static cells much